# Browser crashes

Tags: discussion

For some odd reason, [this seemingly innocuous MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272779/john-g-thompsons-quote-about-contradiction-proof-method) crashes every browser with which I  try to open it on my iPhone.  (This remains true after a phone  reboot.)  It opens perfectly well on other devices.

This has happened occasionally in the past with other questions that seem to have nothing unusual about them.  Am I the only one with this problem, and is there some identifiable feature that causes these particular questions to crash all my phone browsers?

Comment: You should probably include the device model, the OS version, and the versions of whatever you are using to (attempt to) view the question. Also, you may wish to tag this question with [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: Luckily I don't have an iPhone. But Firefox on Android works just fine.

Comment: Did you try to clear the browser cache?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek :  I had not expected clearing the cache to work, because I'm getting the same behavior from multiple browsers.  But I just tried, so that I could report back to you --- and in fact, as expected, clearing the cache makes no difference.